# Adding a radio button value to parent component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

The parent component store all the state.

The function `myChangeHandler` trigger on any `onChange` and change the state

> myChangeHandler(event) {
> this.setState({
> [event.target.name]: event.target.value
> });

and on changing the value of radio button should return in the "Guide is" line
Here is the code and let me know if i miss anything

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      avail:'available',
      $avail:'non-available',
      brandGuideline:'',
    };
    this.myChangeHandler = this.myChangeHandler.bind(this);
  }

  myChangeHandler(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Child username = {this.state.username}
          myChangeHandler = {this.myChangeHandler}
          />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="label">
        <label>
          username
        </label>
        <input
          type='text'
          name='username'
          value={this.props.username}
          onChange={this.props.myChangeHandler}
          />
        <h1>My username: {this.props.username}</h1>
        <div>
          <label>
            We have a Brand Guide
          </label>
          <input 
            type='radio'
            name='brandGuideline'
            value={this.props.$avail}
            onChange={this.props.myChangeHandler}
            />Yes
          <input 
            type='radio'
            name='brandGuideline'
            value={this.props.avail}
            onChange={this.props.myChangeHandler}
            /> No
        </div>
        <h1>Guide is: {this.props.brandGuideline}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
[event.target.name]: event.target.value
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue related to missing props data from parent to child.

Like writing:

`value = {this.state.i_am_not_exist_prop};`

#### 1/2. First mistake

**Before**

```
{/* Parent Before */}
<Child username = 
  {this.state.username}
  myChangeHandler = {this.myChangeHandler}
/>
```

Send `avail` and `$avail` as props.

**Should be:**

```
{/* Parent After step 1*/}
<Child 
 username = {this.state.username}
 myChangeHandler = {this.myChangeHandler}
 avail= {this.state.avail}
 $avail = {this.state.$avail}
/>
```

#### 2/2. Second mistake

Parent component:

```
myChangeHandler(event) {
  console.log([event.target.name]); /* brandGuideline */
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  })
};
```

This `[event.target.name]` = **"brandGuideline"**  (Use `console.log`).
Again you need to send this as a prop to the child.

Pass `brandGuideline`  as a prop:

```
{/* Parent After step 1 & 2 */}
<Child 
  username = {this.state.username}
  myChangeHandler = {this.myChangeHandler}
  avail= {this.state.avail}
  $avail = {this.state.$avail}
  brandGuideline =  {this.state.brandGuideline}
/>
```

#### 1 + 2 Working snippet

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      avail:'available',
      $avail:'non-available',
      brandGuideline:'',
    };
    this.myChangeHandler = this.myChangeHandler.bind(this);
  }

  myChangeHandler(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Child 
          username = {this.state.username}
          myChangeHandler = {this.myChangeHandler}
          avail= {this.state.avail}
          $avail = {this.state.$avail}
          brandGuideline =  {this.state.brandGuideline}
          />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="label">
        <label>
          username
        </label>
        <input
          type='text'
          name='username'
          value={this.props.username}
          onChange={this.props.myChangeHandler}
          />
        <h1>My username: {this.props.username}</h1>
        <div>
          <label>
            We have a Brand Guide
          </label>
          <input 
            type='radio'
            name='brandGuideline'
            value={this.props.$avail}
            onChange={this.props.myChangeHandler}
            />Yes
          <input 
            type='radio'
            name='brandGuideline'
            value={this.props.avail}
            onChange={this.props.myChangeHandler}
            /> No 
        </div>
        <h1>Guide is: {this.props.brandGuideline}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

**Child VS Parent Practices**

If `myChangeHandler` function related **specifically** to the child form and not reusable somehow (Like in your case) - it's better to put the function their instead of sending this function as `prop` from the parent.

`avail` & `$avail` states could be unit to one boolean `available: true`/false (More semantic & usefull for [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)
& Easier to read).

Start here:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html
- https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss to fetch the passed event from child to parent.

```
myChangeHandler(event){
......
}
```

Comment: yes added the event param to the function, it's still  not working on radio values

Comment: This is not the only issue here (Please read my answer).